# On the Dirichlet series for $1/\zeta(s)$ at $\Re(s)=1/2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Suppose that $1/2+it$ is not a zero of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta$, where $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Can $1/\zeta(1/2+it)$ be expressed as a Dirichlet series ?

Comment: I think what you really want to ask is whether the Dirichlet series $\sum\mu(n)/n^{s}$ converges on $\Re(s)=1/2$ except at the zeros of $\zeta(s)$. Note that any number $c$ can be expressed by many Dirichlet series (e.g. by the constant series $c$).

Comment: @GHfromMO, thanks for the correction. So does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)n^{-s} $ converge at $\Re(s)=1/2$ when $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ ?

Comment: (Almost) duplicate of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164874/is-it-possible-to-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mun-sqrtn-diverg).

Comment: @JarekKuben, i didn't know of that question. Indeed, Lucia's answer seems to also address my question. That is, the series $\sum \mu(n)n^{-s}$ seems to be divergent at every point on $\Re(s)=1/2$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Jarek Kuben remarked, the question is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164874/is-it-possible-to-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mun-sqrtn-diverg). Lucia's response there can be adapted here. Briefly, for a fixed $t\in\mathbb{R}$, let us write $M_0(x):=\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)/n^{1/2+it}$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}M_0(x)$ exists, the Riemann hypothesis and the identity
$$\int_0^{\infty} sM_0(e^x)e^{-sx} dx = \frac{1}{\zeta(1/2+it+s)},\qquad\Re(s)>0,$$
hold true. Now, fixing $\Im(s)\neq 0$ and letting $\Re(s)\to 0+$, the right hand side can blow up at the rate of $1/\Re(s)$, while the left hand side is $o(1)/\Re(s)$. This is a contradiction, hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)/n^{1/2+it}$ diverges for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The left hand side doesn't (necessarily) stay bounded, it just diverges more slowly than $o(1/\sigma)$, which is impossible given a pole.

Comment: @Wojowu: You are right, let me fix this.

Comment: @GHfromMO You are very kind, You alway help new member.